# Xampp Apache Virtual Hosts Not Redirecting

Tags: apache, windows-7, xampp

I'm using the Xampp tutorial to set up virtual hosts. My httpd-vhosts.conf looks like this...

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
       DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/"
       ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:8080>
       DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/www/mysite/public_html"
       ServerName mysite.com
</VirtualHost>
```

My hosts entry looks like this..

```
127.0.0.1 mysite.com
```

The hosts part is working because mysite.com lands me on the Apache dashboard (mysite.com/dashboard).

I have the Apache server on 8080, and can browse to my site manually with `http://127.0.0.1/www/mysite/public_html/`

I've tried the virtual hosts config with 80 and 8080.

How can I get it to land on my site?

Edit: On my console (checking syntax) # httpd.exe -t Syntax OK

Comment: I have the same problem - did you ever get an answer?